# Autowired Spring RetryTemplate return nulls in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

In the following code snippet, the autowired retryTemplate instance returns null though it has been declared as a bean and the class is also annonated with @Configuration. Kindly help me understand what is wrong here.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
            return new RetryTemplate();
        }

}

@Component
public class TestClient{

@Autowired
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

public void invokeClient(){

retryTemplate.execute(.....) // this is null
}
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

Comment: Check the package names of your classes. Try first with the same package for all classes like com.example. It will allow smooth auto-configuration by Spring.

Comment: Yeah, all the packages have common names to begin with but issue is still there.

Comment: if you ensure  that the  specified class could be scaned  and  wired into spring context .  another  potential  cause is that test env is  incorrect .how did you test your code ?  junit or some else ? if you are using junit please  add spring env   .  do```@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)``` or
```@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication .class)```

Comment: _all the packages have common names to begin with_ If it is a tree structure of package names then the main application class should be in the root. Otherwise use the same package for all classes or define the packages to be scanned using annotation ComponentScan. And the package structure must be reflected in the file structure. Like com.example.MainClass must be in src/main/java/com/example folder.

Comment: yes, for some reason the packages were not being recognized so had to explicitly include the 'scanBasePackages' attribute in the main class. Thanks for the assistance.